# How to overwrite the name of a file to download in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-packages

I have a function to download a file from Firebase Storage, but I would like to specify the name of the file to download instead of taking the name that is used to store it in Firebase.

Is there a way to do this, maybe with dart.html or with url_launcher?

This is what I have tried but it did not work, it still uses the stored name (`fileName`).

```
  Future<void> downloadFile(String fileName) async {
    debugPrint('Downloading file $fileName...');

    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final pathRef = storageRef.child('path/to/file/$fileName');
    final downloadUrl = await pathRef.getDownloadURL();

    final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: downloadUrl)
      ..target = 'blank'
      ..download = 'newName'; //Supposedly overwrites the name

    anchor.click();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
  AnchorElement(
    href: href,
  )
    ..setAttribute("download", "$fileName")
    ..click();
```

Or like this?

```
final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: downloadUrl)
      ..target = 'blank'
      ..download = '$fileName'; //Supposedly overwrites the name

    anchor.click();
```

Comment: I tried both, none of them works

Comment: Strange, I've used the first one in my project & it is working as expected.

Comment: See: https://i.postimg.cc/q7MczLLt/Screenshot-2023-09-20-at-3-37-22-PM.png

Comment: I think the difference is that I am trying to download an already existing object (it already has a name). I am not building it myself. This does work for empty objects, but I am downloading it from Firebase storage